# match_id for scan operator

Tags: state, azure-data-explorer, kql

I’m trying to use “scan” operator for analyzing state transitions in Azure fleet telemetry. Here is a trimmed down version of data where I’m trying to establish sessions (Each session is basically node states between “Ready” and “HumanInvestigate”). I couldn’t understand the m_id values for the rows highlighted in my output below.

```
datatable(Ts: timespan, nodeState:string)
[
    0m, "Ready",
    1m, "Raw",
    2m, "Ready",
    3m, "HumanInvestigate",
    4m, "Ready",
    5m, "Raw",
    6m, "HumanInvestigate", 
    7m, "Ready",
    8m, "Raw",
    9m, "HumanInvestigate"
]
| sort by Ts asc
| scan with_match_id=m_id with 
(
        step s1: nodeState == "Ready";
        step s2: nodeState != "Ready" and nodeState != "HumanInvestigate";
        step s3: nodeState == "HumanInvestigate";
)
```

[image]

Here is my expected output. Can you please help on how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Not sure it makes sense. sequence of Ready-Raw-Ready-HumanInvestigate seems like 2 sessions where the 1st one didn't came to completion.

Answer (score 2):

‘scan’ implements a linear state machine. It is optimized for speed and memory, so it does a single pass over the data and keeps the memory for storing the states limited to the number of states x the size of a single record. This limitation means that state transitions are forward only, and in case of overlapping sequences the behavior is more complex, sometimes not intuitive. In your case the state transitions are from ‘Ready’ to ‘Raw’ to ‘HumanInvestigate’. At 1m the first match (m_id == 0) moves to step ‘s2’, and step ‘s1’ is empty, ready for a new match. At 2m, the ‘Ready’ matches ‘s1’, starting a new match (m_id == 1). At this point we have to active sequences: m_id==0 at ‘s2’ and m_id==1 at ‘s1’. At 3m there is a match for m_id ==0, moving it from ‘s2’ to ‘s3’.
To achieve your expected output, you should use 2 states:

```
datatable(Ts: timespan, nodeState:string)
[
    0m, "Ready",
    1m, "Raw",
    2m, "Ready",
    3m, "HumanInvestigate",
    4m, "Ready",
    5m, "Raw",
    6m, "HumanInvestigate", 
    7m, "Ready",
    8m, "Raw",
    9m, "HumanInvestigate"
]
| sort by Ts asc
| scan with_match_id=m_id with 
(
        step s1: iff(nodeState == '', nodeState == "Ready", nodeState != "HumanInvestigate");   // a new sequence must start with 'Ready'
        step s2: nodeState == "HumanInvestigate";                                               // a sequence ends with 'HumanInvestigate'
)
 
Ts          nodeState           m_id
00:00:00    Ready               0
00:01:00    Raw                 0
00:02:00    Ready               0
00:03:00    HumanInvestigate    0
00:04:00    Ready               1
00:05:00    Raw                 1
00:06:00    HumanInvestigate    1
00:07:00    Ready               2
00:08:00    Raw                 2
00:09:00    HumanInvestigate    2
```

Comment: Not exactly... `iff(nodeState == '', nodeState == "Ready"` will always be false.